# CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Tags: tensorflow

I have a large network that is somewhat similar to Wavenet. Although (it seems) that my GPU has enough memory, I get an out of memory error on fitting (see logs below).

Any idea?

How can I troubleshoot these kind of CUDA driver issues?

---

2017-12-22 23:32:05.288986: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorf
low\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.6575
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 11.00GiB
Free memory: 10.71GiB

2017-12-22 23:32:05.288986: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorf
low\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0
2017-12-22 23:32:05.288986: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorf
low\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y
2017-12-22 23:32:05.429386: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorf
low\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device
: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)

2017-12-22 23:32:06.131386: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorf
low\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to allocate 10.17G (10922166272 bytes) fro
m device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-12-22 23:32:06.599386: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorf
low\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to allocate 9.15G (9829949440 bytes) from
device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-12-22 23:32:07.332586: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorf
low\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to allocate 8.24G (8846954496 bytes) from
device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
built graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to start your training with a smaller data set and that worked?

How about using generators to gradually input your data? For me that worked quite well (in Keras : model.fit_generator(...))

Comment: Actually when I restarted training the error went away. My question is more general on how to approach such errors (debugging). I guess we need to use the NVidia CUDA profiler.

Comment: Did you have an other Model running in parallel and did not set the allow growth parameter (config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.Session(config=config))? Then it could be that the model before have allocated all the space.

Comment: I cannot find such API in Keras: fit_generator. Did you mean: https://medium.com/@fromtheast/implement-fit-generator-in-keras-61aa2786ce98
?

Comment: You can find it at: https://keras.io/models/sequential/ just search for fit_generator. But yes, it is the same, he also refers to that page.